van der Waals interactions?
I am using Quantum ESPRESSO code and I want to add van der Waals corrections (dftd3) for a 2D material, but I don't know the additional files that must be joined ?
Thanks in advance.

In order to get a useful answer, you need to specify with code are you using.

+1 but can you please make the title better and add 4 more tags?

It might be a good idea to refer to vdw_corr on this site.
https://www.quantum-espresso.org/Doc/INPUT_PW.html

Hi, actually I am wondering about if I need to add other files specified for van derr Waals interactions!!!

No. In quantum espresso, you don't need to add any additional files to add the DTF-D3 van der Waal's corrections. You just have to specify vdw_corr = 'grimme-d3' under the &system namelist in the input file. See the documentation for more.
